# How to sort a list of instances of a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, python-3.6

How can I sort a list that contains classes by a particular instance variable? I want to do alphabetically by the name of the animal in this case.

For example: `my_list = [Animal('dog',3), Animal('cat',5) , Animal('bird',2)]`

I want it sorted like this:  `[Animal('bird',5), Animal('cat',3), Animal('dog',2)]` (Alphabetically)

I don't want it like this:  `[Animal('bird',2), Animal('dog',3), Animal('cat',5)]` (Numerically)

Comment: Your list doesnt seem to contain classes at all, rather, it looks like it contains a bunch of *instances*.

Comment: I tried key = Animal it doesn't work

Comment: `my_list.sort(key=lambda animal: animal.name)`

Comment: Thanks So Much!!